# Помогите с оконным sql запросом

Tags: sql, sql-server

Таблица: `cells (cell_id int, subcell_id int)`
У одного `cell_id` может быть один или несколько `subcell_id`
Как выбрать топ 100 значений `cell_id` со всеми их `subcell_id`?

Comment: Что значит топ100? Какое условие попадания в топ?

Comment: Первые 100 записей из общего числа

Comment: Попробуйте top - https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp

Comment: В БД нет первых и не первых записей, необходимо определить при какой сотировке они первые. Если сортировка не определена, это уже не _первые_, а _случайные_. И кстати, что вы пробовали сделать, какой запрос у вас есть на текущий момент

Comment: А на вскидку, вам нужен dense_rank с сортировкой по cell_id. правда как вы понимаете он выберет 100 минимальных id, а являются ли они "первыми" сами решайте

Comment: *со всеми их subcell_id* - это надо понимать, что одним уровнем вложенности дело не ограничивается, имеется дерево cells-ов, и надо выгрести все sub-sub-...-cells, так? *Первые 100 записей из общего числа* - это первые 100 и все их sub-cells? тогда это будет рекурсивный CTE... А вот оконного тут ничего не будет - независимо от того, надобно обрабатывать вложенность или нет.

Answer (score 0):

Можно вот так:

```
select c.*
from cells c
     inner join (select top 100 cell_id from cells group by cell_id order by cell_id) a on a.cell_id=c.cell_id
```

или так:

```
with ct as 
(select top 100 cell_id from cells group by cell_id order by cell_id)
select c.*
from cells c
     inner join ct on ct.cell_id=c.cell_id
```

В `order by` нужно указать сортировку, по которой нужно выбрать первые 100.